# Webmin error on applying configuration after changing BIND DNS Server

Tags: apache, dns, ndc

I've just installed Webmin and created a zone that appears to be correct, since Check BIND returns

> No errors were found in the BIND configuration file /etc/named.conf or referenced zone files.

The problem was that after hours, my domains still do not resolve, but instead of return UNKNOWN SERVER immediatly it delays about 30 seconds before returning the UNKNOWN SERVER message.

Reading a tutorial on webmin, I found that it was required to click on "Apply Zone", and then it came the error:

> NDC command failed : rndc: neither /etc/rndc.conf nor /etc/rndc.key was found

So reading about the error found "rndc-confgen" and created the key file with "rndc-confgen -a" but it still fails:

> NDC command failed : rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused

So I guess it is a service, but don't know how to start it…
tried "rndc-confgen > /etc/rndc.conf" but now I get this error:

> NDC command failed : WARNING: key file (/etc/rndc.key) exists, but using default configuration file (/etc/rndc.conf) rndc: connect failed: 127.0.0.1#953: connection refused

So I guess that I still need to start the service but have no idea on how to do that… I have a Fedora 14 virtual server, there are these commands available rndc and rndc-confgen.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well, as far as rndc.conf being missing, all you need to do is click the `'setup RNDC'` icon in the webmin `'BIND DNS Server'` screen and confirm to do the setup. This creates the missing `rndc.conf` file.

Comment: Th anks for sharing. Helpful ++